# How to print an object several times in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on a program that should print a pyramid. Base of the pyramid is 14 blocks. Blocks are (30,12) pixels. Dimensions of an applet which pyramid will be printed on is (800,400). Base block starts at (100,380). I figured that if I duplicate that block and move it 30 pixels in x-direction 14 times, I will finish the base. I am having a trouble to do so. I used for loop to duplicate and move the block but doesn`t work. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
import acm.graphics.GRect;

import acm.program.*;

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram 
{

    public static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

    public static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

    public static final int BRICK_IN_BASE = 14;

    public void run() 
    {
        setSize(800,400);
        GRect rec = new GRect (100,380,BRICK_WIDTH,BRICK_HEIGHT);
        for (int i = 0; i<14; i++)
        {
            rec.move(30,0);
            add(rec);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow so could you please explain what do you mean by accept your answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your for loop condition, i is never greater than 14, should be less than.

Also you should make a new Grect, and just change the x value for each new one by 30

```
import acm.graphics.GRect;

import acm.program.*;

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram 
{

    public static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

    public static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

    public static final int BRICK_IN_BASE = 14;

    public void run() 
    {
        setSize(800,400);
        int x = 100;
        int y = 380;
        for (int i = 0; i<14; i++)
        {
            GRect rec = new GRect (x, y,BRICK_WIDTH,BRICK_HEIGHT);
            x += BRICK_WIDTH;
            add(rec);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: how can I print new rec at the new location?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the condition in your for-loop. You're telling the compiler too loop while `i` is bigger than 14, which is never true.
Change it too `i < 14`.

Comment: No problem. If this wasn't a typo, then it would be good to check out some extra documentation about the for-loop as it is an essential piece in Java coding.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one rectangle in your program. The `add()` method adds the same object multiple times; you will need to create a new one every time.

Comment: how can I add new rec at the new location?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't duplicating it, you're simply moving it. Try the following:

```
public void run() {
    setSize(800,400);
    int x=100, y=380;
    GRect rec;
    for (int i = 0; i<BRICK_IN_BASE; i++) {
        rec = new GRect (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
        add(rec);
        x += BRICK_WIDTH;
    }
}
```